# Parsing xs:date with timezone into Joda LocalDate

Tags: java, xsd, jodatime

When parsing dates and times from XML documents into JodaTime objects, I use a common set of conversion utilities, generally using the parsers and formatters supplied by `org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat`.

This works fine in the majority of cases, but this time I'm seeing documents with the `xs:date` value of the format `2010-08-19Z`. This is a perfectly valid `xs:date` value, but none of the standard `ISODateTimeFormat`-generated `LocalDate` parsers I've tried will accept it. The closest I can find is `ISODateTimeFormat.dateParser()`, which will accept the rather odd-looking `2010-08-19TZ`, but not `2010-08-19Z` (note the `T`).

This is all quite irritating, since both Joda and XML Schema are supposed to strictly adhere to the ISO date/time formatting rules, but either one of them isn't, or the spec is fuzzy.

Before I admit defeat and hand-roll a custom format, can anyone point me at a `ISODateTimeFormat`-sourced parser that will read that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that according to ISO-8601, 'Z' is part of the time value.  The 'T' separator is used only to create combined date/time values.  A strict reading of this implies that 'Z' cannot appear after a date without a time value, which can be empty, thus the "odd-looking" `2010-08-18TZ`.

This appears to be a slight impedance mismatch between the definitions of xs:date and ISO-8601.

EDIT: I found a copy of [ISO 8601](http://dotat.at/tmp/ISO_8601-2004_E.pdf).  It does not define the concept of a "time-zoned date" such as is defined in the [XML Schema Datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date) spec.

Rather than writing one from scratch, how about a simple wrapper that converts xs:date instances with timezones into corresponding ISO-8601 values (i.e. just insert the 'T') and then use the existing `ISODateTimeFormat.dateParser()`?

Comment: So the specs don't quite match up. Great :(

Comment: I think ISO-8601 was defined quite a few years ago, long before XML Schemas, and they probably didn't think of dates as rigorously as the XML Schema spec does.